# XML linq need detail info on exception

Tags: c#, xml, linq, exception

I am using xml linq on my project. I am dealing with very large xml's for easy understanding purpose I have mentioned small sample xml.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <StackOverflowReply xmlns="http://xml.stack.com/RRAND01234">
        <processStatus>
            <statusCode1>P</statusCode1>
            <statusCode2>P</statusCode2>
            <statusCode3>P</statusCode3>
            <statusCode4>P</statusCode4>
        </processStatus>
    </StackOverflowReply>
</soap:Body>
```

Following is C# xml linq

```
XNamespace x = "http://xml.stack.com/RRAND01234";
var result = from StackOverflowReply in XDocument.Parse(Myxml).Descendants(x + "Security_AuthenticateReply")
             select new
             {
                status1 = StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "processStatus").Element(x + "statusCode1").Value,
                status2 = StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "processStatus").Element(x + "statusCode2").Value,
                status3 = StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "processStatus").Element(x + "statusCode3").Value,
                status4 = StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "processStatus").Element(x + "statusCode4").Value,
                status5 = StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "processStatus").Element(x + "statusCode5").Value,
              };
```

Here I am getting exception like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Because the tag

```
<statusCode5>
```

was not in my xml.In this case I want to get detail exception message like "Missing tag statusCode5". Please guide me how to get this message from my exception.

Comment: If you want a detailed exception, you'll have to check first if the element exists or try to extract all `statusCode` nodes together. What have you tried to do?

Comment: If you only want the `<statusCodex>` nodes, then grab the `<processStatus>` node, then in your select you can do this: `status1 = (string)processStatus.Element(x + "statusCode4");` - the `(string)` will do an conversion on the element value and simply return null if the element isn't there.

Comment: Yes what you telling is right. This is small xml but I am dealing with large xml about 800 to 1000 lines. The parsing must with more than 5 joins in this I cant predict which tag is missing. If able to get exception message as I except I can got to that place directly and I put your solution. Please let me know u want more detail

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way (that I'm aware of) to find out exactly what element(s) was/were missing in a LINQ to XML statement.  What you can do however is use `(string)` on the element to handle missing elements - but that can get tricky if you have a chain of elements.

That wouldn't work in your current code:

```
status5 = (string)StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "processStatus").Element(x + "statusCode5")
```

Becuase (string) will only work on first element, and the second one is the one that is missing.

You could change your LINQ to focus only on the subnodes, like this:

```
XNamespace x = "http://xml.stack.com/RRAND01234";
var result = from StackOverflowReply in XDocument.Parse(Myxml).Descendants(x + "processStatus")
         select new
         {
            status1 = (string)StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "statusCode1"),
            status2 = (string)StackOverflowReply..Element(x + "statusCode2"),
            status3 = (string)StackOverflowReply..Element(x + "statusCode3"),
            status4 = (string)StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "statusCode4"),
            status5 = (string)StackOverflowReply.Element(x + "statusCode5"),
          };
```

However, if your XML is complex and you have different depths (nested elements), you'll need a more robust solution to avoid a bunch of conditional operator checks or multiple queries.

I have something that might help if that is the case - I'll have to dig it up.

**EDIT For More Complex XML**

I've had similar challenges with some XML I have to deal with at work.  In lieu of an easy way to determine what node was the offending node, and not wanting to have hideously long ternary operators, I wrote an extension method that worked recursively from the specified starting node down to the one I was looking for.

Here's a somewhat simple and contrived example to demonstrate.

```
<SomeXML>
  <Tag1>
    <Tag1Child1>Value1</Tag1Child1>
    <Tag1Child2>Value2</Tag1Child2>
    <Tag1Child3>Value3</Tag1Child3>
    <Tag1Child4>Value4</Tag1Child4>
  </Tag1>
  <Tag2>
    <Tag2Child1>
      <Tag2Child1Child1>SomeValue1</Tag2Child1Child1>
      <Tag2Child1Child2>SomeValue2</Tag2Child1Child2>
      <Tag2Child1Child3>SomeValue3</Tag2Child1Child3>
      <Tag2Chidl1Child4>SomeValue4</Tag2Child1Child4>
    <Tag2Child1>
    <Tag2Child2>
      <Tag2Child2Child1>
        <Tag2Child2Child1Child1 />
        <Tag2Child2Child1Child2 />
    </Tag2Child2>
  </Tag2>
</SomeXML>
```

In the above XML, I had no way of knowing (prior to parsing) if any of the children elements were empty, so I after some searching and fiddling I came up with the following extension method:

```
public static XElement GetChildFromPath(this XElement currentElement, List<string> elementNames, int position = 0)
{

    if (currentElement == null || !currentElement.HasElements)
    {
        return currentElement;
    }

    if (position == elementNames.Count - 1)
    {
        return currentElement.Element(elementNames[position]);
    }
    else
    {
        XElement nextElement = currentElement.Element(elementNames[position]);
        return GetChildFromPath(nextElement, elmenentNames, position + 1);
    }
}
```

Basically, the method takes the `XElement` its called on, plus a `List<string>` of the elements in path order, with the one I want as the last one, and a position (index in the list), and then works it way down the path until it finds the element in question or runs out of elements in the path.  It's not as elegant as I would like it to be, but I haven't had time to refactor it any.

I would use it like this (based on the sample XML above):

```
MyClass myObj = (from x in XDocument.Parse(myXML).Descendants("SomeXML")
                select new MyClass() {
                    Tag1Child1 = (string)x.GetChildFromPath(new List<string>() {
                                 "Tag1", "Tag1Child1" }),
                    Tag2Child1Child4 = (string)x.GetChildFromPath(new List<string>() {
                                 "Tag2", "Tag2Child1", "Tag2Child1Child4" }),
                    Tag2Child2Child1Child2 = (string)x.GetChildFromPath(new List<string>() {
                                 "Tag2", "Tag2Child2", "Tag2Child2Child1", 
                                 "Tag2Child2Child1Child2" })
                }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Not as elegant as I'd like it to be, but at least it allows me to parse an XML document that may have missing nodes without blowing chunks.  Another option was to do something like:

```
Tag2Child2Child1Child1 = x.Element("Tag2") == null ? 
                         "" : x.Element("Tag2Child2") == null ? 
                         "" : x.Element("Tag2Child2Child1") == null ? 
                         "" : x.Element("Tag2Child2Child1Child2") == null ? 
                         "" : x.Element("Tag2")
                               .Element("Tag2Child2")
                               .Element("Tag2Child2Child1") 
                               .Element("Tag2Child2Child1Child2").Value
```

That would get really ugly for an object that had dozens of properties.

Anyway, if this is of use to you feel free to use/adapt/modify as you need.

Comment: I put simple xml to make people understand my problem. My xml is complex and has different depths. Your answer works if last child is missed but not for any parent node. I tried many ways and now I decided if I able to get missing Element name in exception log will help 90% for me. Thank you for consideration.

Comment: @YasinJamesBond - I've added something that I developed and used at work for a similar situation.  Hopefully it will be of some use to you.